# Include page numbers in a \cite argument?

Tags: citing, optional-arguments, page

I'm quoting the same book quite often, it's just different page numbers. So what I want to do is putting the page numbers in an argument while citing, so I don't have to create a new bib entry for the same book over and over.

```
beinhaltet allerdings nicht bereits ein Spiel ist\cite{chou2019actionable}.
```

should become something like

```
beinhaltet allerdings nicht bereits ein Spiel ist\cite[pages={35-39}]{chou2019actionable}.
```

I use the following lines to create the bib, I think it's Bibtex? I used a template and it's my first document created with LaTeX so I'm still learning.. I think there's no package loaded that belongs to the bibliography:

```
\bibliography{bibliography/references}{}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

My bib entry for the refered book looks like this:

```
@inbook{chou2019actionable,
  title={Actionable gamification: Beyond points, badges, and leaderboards},
  author={Chou, Yu-kai},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Packt Publishing Ltd},
  pages={1}
}
```

Comment: This is already supported, just use: `\cite[S.~35--39]{chou2019actionable}`. Small explanation in case you don't know: `~` is an unbreakable space, `--` is an endash, which should be preferred over a hyphen to indicate a range.

Comment: This doesn't work, what does the "S." stand for?

Comment: **S**eite, obviously …

Comment: That's the usual German abbreviation for page :P It would be easier to help you if you showed a minimal example that includes the packages you use to get your bibliography. The solution my first comment proposes works with `biblatex`.

Comment: I was wondering why the syntax is German so it wasn't too obvious for me.
I will edit some more info in the post above! :)

Comment: It's not part of the syntax, it can be whatever you want it to be.

Comment: I will try to read into Biblatex and use your solution again! :)

Comment: Oh, I get the confusion now! I have to cite in IEEE/numeric style. Therefore I do not want to have the cited pages from the book in the running text but I just want to deliver the argument in order to have it shown in the bibliography. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: @maur1ce; there is a `biblatex-ieee` package.

Comment: Thank you, good hint. Loaded this one instead of the "numeric" one! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting a full example here, just because it's easier than in the comments …
Make of it what you will :-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mwe.bib}
  @book{jane1980,
  author    = "Jane Doe",
  title     = "Matrix Computations",
  edition   = "4th Edition",
  publisher = "The Johns Hopkins University Press",
  address   = "Baltimore, Maryland",
  year      = "2013",
  }

@inbook{chou2019actionable,
  title={Actionable gamification: Beyond points, badges, and leaderboards},
  author={Chou, Yu-kai},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Packt Publishing Ltd},
  pages={1}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}

According to some sources “Lorem ipsum novum.” \cite[p.~20]{jane1980}. 
\citeauthor{chou2019actionable} readily agrees \cite[pp.~35--39]{chou2019actionable}. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to mention that I have to cite in the numeric style. Therefore in the text you would only see the hint "[1]" and I can not add page numbers to that. The page numbers must be included in the bibliography then...

Comment: I'm a Humanities™ guy myself, so I wouldn't know how to quote in IEEE style, but this really looks like an elaborate footnote/endnote kind of thing. Are you really supposed to have multiple bibliography entries for multiple page ranges? If so, I am not aware of a way to automate that.

Comment: Actually, at least according to some style guides page numbers etc. should be fine. **[3, Th. 1]; [3, Lemma 2]; [3, pp. 5–10]; [3, eq. (2)]; [3, Fig. 1]; [3, Appendix I]; [3, Sec. 4.5]; [3, Ch. 2, pp. 5–10]; [3, Algorithm 5].** Source: https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf I have amended my solution.

Comment: Actually you are right, it would result in quite a messy bibliography. Pretty sure "[1, S. 5-7]" is fine as style now. Thanks a bunch for your help!